# VB.Net Linq from clause doesnt allow late binding

Tags: vb.net, performance, linq, asp.net-core, .net-standard

I am developing an ASP.NET Core 2 project in c# that uses a VB.Net Standard 2.0 class library to access a table from database but i am not be able to compile this code because a "Late binding issue" in my linq code:

```
Dim resultados As List(Of ENTIDAD) = (From row In _dtData.Rows
                                              Select New ENTIDAD() With {
                                                ._IDENTIDAD = If((TypeOf row("IDENTIDAD") Is DBNull), DirectCast(Nothing, System.Nullable(Of Integer)), Convert.ToInt32(row("IDENTIDAD"))),
                                                ._CODENTIDAD = row("CODENTIDAD").ToString(),
                                                ._NOMBRE = row("NOMBRE").ToString()
                       }).Skip(currentPage).Take(If(pageSize = 0, totalrecords, pageSize)).ToList()
```

I know that is a .NET Standard 2.0 problem because it have been ever working for me using NET Framework. However, i have replaced with this and it works:

```
        Dim oList = From w In _dtData.Rows
                    Select w

        For Each row As System.Data.DataRow In oList.Skip(currentPage).Take(If(pageSize = 0, totalrecords, pageSize))
            Dim objClase As New ENTIDAD()

            objClase._IDENTIDAD = If((TypeOf row("IDENTIDAD") Is DBNull), DirectCast(Nothing, System.Nullable(Of Integer)), Convert.ToInt32(row("IDENTIDAD")))
            objClase._CODENTIDAD = row("CODENTIDAD").ToString()
            objClase._NOMBRE = row("NOMBRE").ToString()

            resultados.Add(objClase)
        Next
```

but i am not sure that is the best way. I am worried about performance when i get long amount of data. Is there anyway to acomplish it? Is this the best way?

Comment: What doesn't work in the first query?

Comment: Why don't you use LINQ to Datasets?

Comment: I can't use LINQ to DataSet in NET Standard 2.0. As they says: "We currently don't have plans to include the precursor of EF, Linq-to-SQL, spatial support, OleDb, ODBC, or the (deprecated) Oracle client on System.Data."